# Hash Sum mismatch error when I try to install docker

Tags: apt, virtualbox, docker

I am running ubuntu 19.10 on VirtualBox.

When I run the following commands to install [docker-ce](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

sudo apt-get install containerd.io
```

I get the Hash Sum mismatch error(see below). I carefully followed all of the steps, there. Not sure I am missing.

I have seen [this ans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273441/404099) and looked at [this](https://www.poftut.com/apt-command-hash-sum-mismatch-error-and-solution-on-ubuntu-debian-mint-kali/) as well, but could not get much. I am new to ubuntu.

I have carefully followed [this ans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363058) well till the end.

I encountered this with Ubuntu 18.04 as well. Pulled 19.10 hoping that this would go away, but in vain.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
useradmin@ubuntuserver:~$ sudo apt-get install containerd.io
[sudo] password for vivekadmin:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  containerd.io
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 20.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 91.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan/stable amd64 containerd.io amd64 1.2.13-1 [20.1 MB]
Err:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan/stable amd64 containerd.io amd64 1.2.13-1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:6d0224e484e515aa1f5409534174a0e8f446b681cdfbd0ec900217021d8f67348b56bb1964c66b300e24d084be3a06dd9df326900a07b3cc0daaf1f2503f6dfe
   - SHA256:4655707011b13bce3ac9c64b73096925bc863f64b8ab1d13aa316bce923181a0
   - SHA1:6c6a9e5d83ccd81e40b064b1418700e4027c4797 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:a564ecd3f499c32fa0d7679efeb1ac35 [weak]
   - Filesize:20122210 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:6e52d4d1e69ca5a4a3764c5e9068078022580d0561500b730e85e4dd9972f8bbf0efc3cd501e79a0f41a5b9689a8cd13888fff7ca2f8a0b324f54cc8a8419edf
   - SHA256:5a8ca72df78dfab8259346baed4000563fcaeb138bf27955e192b47a27573cb6
   - SHA1:bb28cb003a49915621a1ea6424569c8ecf03781b [weak]
   - MD5Sum:5b1847801ea188d60d39e7c18a47e6f3 [weak]
   - Filesize:20122210 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 03 Mar 2020 04:23:44 +0000
Fetched 20.1 MB in 34s (587 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/eoan/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.2.13-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:6d0224e484e515aa1f5409534174a0e8f446b681cdfbd0ec900217021d8f67348b56bb1964c66b300e24d084be3a06dd9df326900a07b3cc0daaf1f2503f6dfe
    - SHA256:4655707011b13bce3ac9c64b73096925bc863f64b8ab1d13aa316bce923181a0
    - SHA1:6c6a9e5d83ccd81e40b064b1418700e4027c4797 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:a564ecd3f499c32fa0d7679efeb1ac35 [weak]
    - Filesize:20122210 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:6e52d4d1e69ca5a4a3764c5e9068078022580d0561500b730e85e4dd9972f8bbf0efc3cd501e79a0f41a5b9689a8cd13888fff7ca2f8a0b324f54cc8a8419edf
    - SHA256:5a8ca72df78dfab8259346baed4000563fcaeb138bf27955e192b47a27573cb6
    - SHA1:bb28cb003a49915621a1ea6424569c8ecf03781b [weak]
    - MD5Sum:5b1847801ea188d60d39e7c18a47e6f3 [weak]
    - Filesize:20122210 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 03 Mar 2020 04:23:44 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, finally I resolved it and here is how.

Instead of the command

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install containerd.io
```

I have used the following, first downloading the packages and then installing them.

```
curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/eoan/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.2.13-1_amd64.deb
curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/eoan/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-eoan_amd64.deb
curl -k -O -L https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/eoan/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-eoan_amd64.deb


sudo apt install ./containerd.io_1.2.13-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./docker-ce-cli_19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-eoan_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./docker-ce_19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-eoan_amd64.deb
```

I had searched on the net to first get to the package page. For example for [here is the link for docker_ce](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.10/docker-ce-stable-amd64/docker-ce_19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-eoan_amd64.deb.html).

I found that apt install is inconsistent.

The other approach that worked for me was

```
sudo dpkg -i ./packageName
```